# Why does kernel density of positive data display negative values?

Tags: kernel-smoothing, density-estimation

A random data vector containing non-negative values summing to 1 is:

```
0.02470075959639532
0.031345388546362596
0.03153954918372276
0.036318448810604316
0.06340725977285551
0.11029259333124006
0.11707200006829813
0.11875407465704997
0.15147816276285112
0.3150917632706202
```

but the kernel density estimator looks like:

[image]

why does the x-axis reach past -0.1 even though no data observation is less than 0.0247? I know the line is supposed to be smoothed, but I don't see what prevents kernel density estimation from just truncating at, or dropping off, at or much nearer to 0 on the x-axis like it should, rather than taking a long time to taper. (this is a general question about the underlying maths, but if it means anything, the pandas `plot.kde()` function in python was used)

Comment: Why does your random data vector sum up to 1?

Comment: simulating probabilities

Comment: This complete setup is not correct, just as you wouldn't want to plot a histogram over these values. KDE operates over data points that are iid.

Comment: how did you tell the data was i.i.d. in the first place? and what is the counterpart for density estimation that can admit non-i.i.d.?

Comment: Your data is not iid, it sums up to 1. It's like a discretised histogram. KDE treats those values as *data points* and puts some kernel density (here Gaussian) over those. I don't know any general method for your query (don't suppose it exists as well).

Comment: re: "just as you wouldn't want to plot a histogram over these values" and "it's like a discretised histogram". a discretized histogram is ok for a dataset of probabilities, but a histogram isn't?

Comment: Histograms are always discretized, so ignore that additional word in my explanation. I meant your data is like a normalized histogram (since it sums up to 1). A kde or another histogram over it feels like you're calculating a histogram of histogram values. Also, your data sample is not like a typical random sample, sampled from a distribution $f(x)$ to be approximated. Simply put, I cannot extend your data with new observations, since it wouldn't sum up to 1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111850/discussion-between-develarist-and-gunes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

kde in [pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.kde.html) uses Gaussian kernels. Basically, it puts a gaussian over each data point and sums up the densities (with proper normalisation). So, you'll always have tails extending over your data range. Basically, KDE says that although there is no data in this range, there could have been data in another random sample and I'm assigning some small mass to represent that possibility.

Comment: so if I extract the probability values that the kde generator came up with, that data series would contain some negative values?

Comment: what do you mean by extracting probability values? do you mean sampling from approximated distribution?

Comment: kde measures the smoothed line right and tells pyplot what to show, so you extract the values from the function itself somehow, even though it possess no such readily-available attribute to call them out, or extract them directly from the generated plot as a data series of same length to the source data (each kde probability sample corresponds to one of the raw source's probability samples)